# Anycharts 6.2.0 - "TypeError: this.b.getSVG is not a function"

Tags: javascript, svg, anychart

`Anycharts 6.2.0` here. I'm trying to implement the `getSVG()` function, so I made a small test, very similar to the one that appears in the online docs:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var chart = null ;
      // HTML5 chart
      AnyChart.renderingType = anychart.RenderingType.SVG_ONLY;
      chart = new AnyChart() ;
      if (chart!=null) {
        chart.width = '100%' ;
        chart.height = '100%';
        chart.wMode = 'transparent' ;
        chart.useBrowserResize = true ;
        chart.setXMLFile(xmlFile);
        chart.write("sepChartContainer");
        alert(chart.getSVG(true)) ;
      }
  </script>
```

But on the browser web console I get this error:

`TypeError:` `this.b.getSVG is not a function`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider moving to the latest version of AnyChart. Version 6.2 has been released 10 years ago and no longer supported.